# How can I group td together?

Tags: html, css

The following works as desired (almost entirely). The one issue is that some rows in the table will have multiple "flags" (in this example, both a data type "string" and the word "REQUIRED". In cases like this, the style breaks because the first flag takes up the full 180px area. Any suggestions on how to both make sure both flags can fit in the 180px and also that they are right aligned?

```css
/* place your custom CSS overrides here */

.toc-wrapper .logo {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 10%;
}

.content > aside p {
    display: inline;
}

/***** PROPERTIES/ATTRIBUTES TABLE *****/

table.properties {
    display: block;
    margin: 18px 0;
    width: 50%;
}

table.properties thead {
    display: none;
}

table.properties tbody {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

table.properties tr {
    display: list-item;
    padding: 17px 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

table.properties tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eceeef;
}

table.properties tr:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

table.properties tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dde1e3;
}

table.properties tr:nth-child(even) > td,
table.properties tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
    background: transparent;
}

table.properties td {
    line-height: 21px; /* must be half tr min-height */
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;

    /* MIDDLE TDs */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font: normal normal 400 normal 12px inherit;
    color: rgb(147, 157, 163);
}

table.properties td:first-child {
    /* FIRST TD */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgb(41, 46, 49);
}

table.properties td:nth-child(3) {
    /* THIRD TD */
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f2a359;
}

table.properties tr > td:last-child {
    /* LAST TD */
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgb(76, 85, 90);

    /* OVERRIDES */
    float: none; /* float: left due to td settings (FOR ALL EXCEPT LAST CHILD) */
}

/* COLUMN VIEW */
/*@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {*/
    .content > h1,
    .content > h2,
    .content > h3,
    .content > h4,
    .content > h5,
    .content > h6,
    .content > p,
    .content > table,
    .content > ul,
    .content > ol,
    .content > aside,
    .content > dl {
        padding-left: 40px;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }

    .content > ul,
    .content > ol,
    .content > dl {
        padding-left: 55px;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }

    table.properties tr {
        clear: both;
        min-height: 42px; /* must be twice td line-height */
    }

    table.properties td {
        text-align: right;
        float: left;
    }

    table.properties tr > td:nth-child(1) {
        width: 180px;
    }
    table.properties tr > td:nth-child(2) {
        clear: left;
        width: 180px;
    }

    table.properties tr > td:nth-child(3) {
    }

    table.properties tr > td:last-child {
        margin-left: 200px;

        /* OVERRIDES */
        width: auto; /* width: 180px due to td settings (FOR ALL EXCEPT LAST CHILD) */
        text-align: left; /* text-align: right due to td settings (FOR ALL EXCEPT LAST CHILD) */
        clear: none; /* clear: left due to td settings (FOR ALL EXCEPT LAST CHILD) */
    }
/*}*/

/* STACKED VIEW */
/*@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .content > h1,
    .content > h2,
    .content > h3,
    .content > h4,
    .content > h5,
    .content > h6,
    .content > p,
    .content > table,
    .content > aside {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .content > ul,
    .content > ol,
    .content > dl {
        padding-left: 35px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    table.properties td {
        padding-left: 4px;
    }

    table.properties td:nth-child(3) {
        padding-left: 0;
        clear: left;
    }

    table.properties td:first-child,
    table.properties td:last-child {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    table.properties tr > td:last-child {
        padding-top: 10px;

        clear: both;
    }
}
*/
```

```html
<table class="properties">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Property</th>
<th>Data Type</th>
<th>Flags</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>send_id</td>
<td>string</td>
<td>REQUIRED</td>
<td>The unique identifier of the send</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>send_id</td>
<td>string</td>
<td></td>
<td>The unique identifier of the send</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>send_id</td>
<td>string</td>
<td></td>
<td>The unique identifier of the send</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What about `table.properties tr > td:nth-child(3) { clear: left; width: 180px; }`, although I would rethink using a table for this maybe?

Comment: I'd consider putting your "flags" in a single td and let word break/wrap handle the rest (with `text-align: right`). If you ever add any more flags, I can't see any other easily flexible way.

Comment: Further to what Lewis said, you could end up with two `<td>` tags under each `<tr>` and end up with how tables are kind of intended to be organized (into rows and columns, with the columns being the `td` tags). Then under the `td` for the flags you would add each line with a line break, and organize them with additional markup depending on the flag. Then you won't have to add weird margins and stuff to force the `td` tags to look the way you want.